# Connect to a local MySQL database from a remote computer using phpMyAdmin

Tags: c#, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm a newbie.. So, please forgive me if it's a simple question :)

I'm developing a system to get some specific data and store it to a database using C#. I have almost finished the system.

I'm using a MySql database running locally on my machine. I need this database to be accessed remotely so that my employer can view the data. He told me to create a phpMyAdmin interface for the database, but I don't have experience with this.

I need the solution to be free, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is free.  You just have to download and install it on the machine with MySql.  You will also need a WAMP stack (PHP web server hosting, such as the free [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) package) to execute the phpMyAdmin website, and [open the ports](http://portforward.com/) in your router to allow viewing the webpage remotely.  Also there might be configuration settings in phpMyAdmin to allow remote access, but all these things have been done many times before and you should be able to find lots of help by googling.

Comment: So, you mean I should make my laptop as a server? I don't have a real IP and I'm  traveling a lot. My employer wants to view the database anytime too. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use dyndns service (http://dyn.com/dns/) to sync your IP with a name like custom.dyndns.tv which your employer can use and would be able to find your laptop as long as it's online and connected to the Internet.  Otherwise, your data needs to be somewhere else besides local, such as a hosting account with bluehost.com or some other web host.  Do you have access to any other machines that are more stable and stationary?

Comment: I will not be connecting from the same IP all the time. So, I think that dyndns idea is not applicable. I checked bluesoft.com and found that it's not free (I need a free solution if possible). Yes, I have access to a stationary machine, but with a limited upload speed.

Comment: Right hosting is not free, sorry I should have said that.  The point of dyndns service (which *is* free) is that your IP doesn't have to be the same.  The dyndns service syncs your ip, so if you get a hostname from them liks Yas_EG.dyndns.tv, this domain name will always point to whatever the latest IP you connected as.  A little program runs on your laptop, and it automatically syncs up with their server so the domain name always points to your IP every time it changes.